# Does Google Play Games Service use Android Advertising ID?

Tags: android, google-play-games, google-advertising-id

The new Google policy requires app to not transmit Android Advertising ID (AAID) when targeting for both children and adults. I would like to check if Play Games Service is using Android Advertising ID and disable it accordingly.